# Apache proxy to Lighttpd: changing $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in php

Tags: php, apache, proxy, lighttpd, http-host

I have a WordPress blog running on lighttpd-1.4.19, listening at www00:81. On the same host, apache-2.2.11 listens on port 80, which creates a proxy connection from `http://blog.mydomain.org:80` to `http://blog.mydomain.org:81` (both being the same physical machine).

The Apache virtualhost looks as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.mydomain.org
    ProxyRequests Off

    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://blog.mydomain.org:81/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://blog.mydomain.org:81/
</VirtualHost>
```

Using `debug.log-request-handling = "enable"`, I get the following log entry when I browse `http://blog.mydomain.org:80` (notice the `Host` headers):

```
2010-05-10 08:47:14: (request.c.294) fd: 6 request-len: 853 
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: blog.mydomain.org:81
[...]

2010-05-10 08:47:15: (request.c.294) fd: 8 request-len: 754 
GET /wp-content/uploads/2010/01/image.gif?w=280 HTTP/1.1
Host: www00:81
```

My problem: as far as I know, the PHP environment variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is set to that `Host` header variable. Unfortunately, WordPress uses that variable in their system to create URLs to pictures on the blog. These URLs won't be accessible behind a firewall of course. How can I force the host header to be `blog.mydomain.org` instead of `blog.mydomain.org:81`, respectively `www00:81`? I already added `set server.name = "blog.mydomain.org"` to my `lighttpd.conf`, but this didn't work.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried editing your [`wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)? It should be possible to override the automatic host detection.

Namely:

- [WP_SITEURL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29)
- [WP_HOME](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Blog_address_.28URL.29)
- [WP_CONTENT_URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content)

Comment: A `print_r` on `$_SERVER` shows `[HTTP_HOST] => blog.mydomain.org:81`, so it does contain the port number. Unfortunately I can can't move `blog.mydomain.org` to port 80 (this is a really complicated story; because of multiple reasons I want to run the blog on a separate web-service). And yes, I should've posted it on serverfault.com.

Comment: @watain oh, I stand corrected re the `HTTP_HOST`, sorry. I misread you. Updated my answer.

Comment: No, I haven't edited my `wp-config.php` yet. What would I have to change? I changed both `WordPress address (URL)` and `Blog address (URL)` in the wordpress admin panel to the correct value (`http://blog.mydomain.org`), but that didn't change much either. EDIT: Ok. I'll check out these variables.

Comment: @watain it *should* be possible to change every aspect of WordPress to a certain host different from what the browser thinks is the current one. I can't say for 100% sure because I've never done it but it should work.

Comment: It seems like all URL are ok, but not the ones used for pictures which are included in a blog post. They always start with `http://www00:81/...`.

Comment: @watain yes, those are probably hard coded in your database. you would have to replace them there using `UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = REPLACE(fieldname, 'http://www00:81', 'http://blog.mydomain.org');` be sure to make a backup beforehand. I think the table name is "posts", check out which field contains the HTML.

Comment: Alright, looks like your SQL query solved the problem :). I needed to modify `wp_content` and `guid` of the table `wp_posts`. Thank you very much!